# Running second code(jar) from one's jar main class

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

What I need is to run a jar file which is inside another jar file from my java code.
I have this turnOffClient.jar file which I put in my ChatSystemClient.jar file and what I want to do is execute(start,run) turnOffClient.jar file from xClient.jar main-class code.
I have tried:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(this.getClass().getResource("/jars/TurnOffClient.jar").toString());
```

Also:

```
TurnOffClient.main(args);
```

It seems to work but when I close the first java application the second one closes too,which I don't want.
My directories:
https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/253x254q90/856/ztuz.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a bad programming practice, instead create a new class that calls both your programs.

Example:

```
Program a;
Program b;

    a.run();
    while(a.isAlive()){
       if( /*we need to run program b*/){
         b.run();
         break;
       }

    }
```

Comment: Do you *really* want to run a tight loop of `a.isAlive`? That seems to me like tying up a processor for no gain...

Comment: @tucuxi Good point actually, Probably its a good idea to put the process into sleep, just after if statement add: Thread.sleep(100);

Comment: I did it like this:

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  Thread t = new Thread(new ChatSystemClient());
  t.start();
  new TurnOffClient().start();
 }
Created new thread cause I need to run both programs at the same time.
But whenever I close one of them both of them closes,but I only want to close the one who has been clicked.

Comment: that shouldn't happen really unless they are related somehow.I can't really say why this happens unless I see the code. however Try the following: close thread one and see what happens to thread two, then vice versa. if you see some odd behaviour then something wrong with your code...

Answer (score 0):

Are these graphical applications? You could make application **A** (the one that opens application **B**) not-truly-close when "closed", but continue to work in the background until application **B** is actually closed.

When **B** is launched, the JVM is just instantiating a special class from B (call it `BMain`) and calling its `public void main(String[] args)` method. There is no reason you cannot call that method directly from your own code (instead of via `getRuntime().exec()`):

```
BMain.main("my arguments here");
```

If your **A** process does not immediately end when its window is closed (hunt down and eliminate any `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` instances in **A**, assuming you are using Swing), and it calls **B**'s main as above, **B** will run normally even when **A** is "closed".